# Parse file upon initialization and make accessible to all classes

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop, pyramid

Essentially, when the pyramid app starts, I need to parse a file and make the data from that file available to the whole app. On top of that, I need to monitor the file for changes, it's essentially a config file. I was considering just making a singleton and initializing it when the app starts up when Configurator is initialized. Is that the best way to do it, or are there any other approaches I should follow/consider?

Sorry, new to pyramid and python, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in many places, [Singleton is considered a code smell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons) and as such, should be avoided. IMHO, a `Singleton` *can* be used if there's a reasonable trade-off. For example, if using a `Singleton` boosts the performance in a significant way. In your situation this just might be the case: If the config file is used in many places across you app, reading the file multiple times might impact your performance. However, if you choose to use a Singleton, keep in mind the dangers that come with it.

To answer you question, I don't think it's possible to tell what's the *best* way for you to go, because that depends on your specific app. I can only suggest that you take into account the pros and cons of each option, and making your choice depending on your needs.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the OP's question (even your second paragraph just says "there are different ways" without mentioning any of those ways).

Answer (score 1):

We do this exact thing (with Pyramid and global app settings) with a top-level `app/config.py` which is just a list of config variables (and possibly their defaults). Then in our main function we load the config and set the various attributes of the `config` module so the application can use them.

For example, here's `app/config.py`:

```
image_dir = '/mnt/images'
s3_access_key = None  # these must be specified in the config INI
s3_secret_key = None
```

Here's the relevant part of our config INI (eg: `app/development.ini`):

```
[app:main]
app.image_dir = ./test_images
app.s3_access_key = ABCD1234...
app.s3_secret_key = EFGH5678...
```

And the relevant config loading code in our `app/main.py`:

```
from . import config

def main(global_config, **settings):
    config.image_dir = settings.get('app.image_dir', config.image_dir)
    config.s3_access_key = settings['app.s3_access_key']
    config.s3_secret_key = settings['app.s3_secret_key']

    configurator = Configurator(settings=settings)
    # ... configure and add routes
    configurator.scan()

    return configurator.make_wsgi_app()
```

And then other application code can simply `from app import config` or `from . import config` and use the settings, for example: `os.path.join(config.image_dir, 'my_image.jpg')`